# Using unseakable stream more than once

Tags: c#, stream

```
using (var stream = GetS3ObjectStream(fooObj))
{
    WriteStreamToFtp(stream, "ftp://firstserver");
    WriteStreamToFtp(stream, "ftp://SecondServer"); 
}
```

First one would work, but the second one will create just an empty file

`GetS3ObjectStream` gets a stream for Amazon Simple storage object. It's unseakable stream and you can't change the cursor position in it.

Now, I either have to somehow restrict to use the stream object more than once or I have to to move the cursor to the beginning.

any ideas?

upd: yeah of course you can simply save the stream in temp. variable, but if you don't wanna do that, what then? is it ok to make methods that take streams and leave them with such side-effects?
what if I close and dispose the source stream in the method?

Comment: I guess you could create a stream splitter which reads a stream once and writes it to two different destinations whilst reading it (in blocks). But it’s probably not worth the effort unless you really need the efficiency.

Comment: temp var won't help at all. You'd need to clone the actual stream, and that's not possible. You could copy it to a `MemoryStream` or a file, but that's expensive for large files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s an example of how it may be done reading the stream just once (without initializing a temporary copy of the stream’s contents).

This assumes that you can replace your `WriteStreamToFtp` call with access to the actual target stream. Note that the `FtpStream` constructor is placeholder code.

```
using (var source = GetS3ObjectStream(fooObj))
using (var target1 = new FtpStream("ftp://firstserver"))
using (var target2 = new FtpStream("ftp://SecondServer"))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (true)
    {
        int count = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (count == 0)
            break;

        target1.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        target2.Write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I’d mentioned it in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856075/using-unseakable-stream-more-than-once/10856642#comment14141424_10856075) before that, but then realized it wasn’t as complex as I thought and decided to give some sample code.

Answer (score 7):

You can either re-create your stream or buffer it into a `byte[]` or `MemoryStream` before use.

Edit: I forgot to mention a solution which does **not buffer**:

1. Open the two destination streams
2. Open the source stream
3. Until the source is drained, read a buffer of N bytes and write the buffer to both destination streams (you can even do the writing in parallel using Parallel.Invoke())

Comment: so you're saying I got to read the stream and save it in temp var, right? Well, it will cost cpu time and memory and whatnot. Is there a better solution?

Comment: @Agzam: No ...not really. I was thinking the same solution as @usr. I would use `byte[]` personally rather than MemoryStream. Either option is *not* a non-elegant solution to the problem. Very acceptable IMO. :)